# How to force dependency / linkage of genes in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

For a current project, I want to use genetic algorithms - currently I had a look at the **jenetics** library.

How can I force that some genes are dependent on each other? I want to map CSS on the gene, f.e. I have genes indicating if an image is displayed, and in case it is also the  respective height and width. So I want to have those genes as a group togheter, as it would make no sense that after a crossover, the chrosome would indicate something like "no image" - height 100px - width 0px.

Is there a method to do so? Or maybe another library (in **java**) which supports this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just ignore those ? Wouldn't leaving them untied somewhat improve the random side of the genetic algorithm ?

Comment: So you mean, to let the algorithm generate those chromosomes and then prove if they are reasonable? That could also be an option, but for efficancy I would like to already impose those constraints at the generation.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of real genes are 'junk' or only have value when other genes are turned on .

Answer (score 1):

You want to embed more knowledge into your system to reduce the search space.

If it would be knowledge about the structure of the solution, I would propose taking a look at [grammatical evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_evolution) (GE). Your knowledge appears to be more about valid combinations of codons, so GE is not easily applicable.

It might be possible to combine a few features into a single codon, but this may be undesirable and/or unfeasible (e.g. due to great number of possible combinations).

But in fact you don't have an issue here:

- it's fine to have meaningless genotypes — they will be removed due to the selection pressure
- it's fine to have meaningless codon sequences — it's called "bloat"; bloat is quite common to some evolutionary algorithms (usually discussed in the context of [genetic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming)) and is not strictly bad; fighting with bloat too much can reduce the search performance

Answer (score 0):

If you know how your genome is encoded - that is, you know which sequences of chromosomes form groups - then you could extend (since you mention jenetics) `io.jenetics.MultiPointCrossover` to avoid splitting groups.  (Source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenetics/jenetics/blob/master/jenetics/src/main/java/io/jenetics/MultiPointCrossover.java).)

It could be as simple as storing ranges of genes which form groups if one of the random cut indexes would split a group, adjusting the index to the nearest end of the group.  (Of course this would cause a statistically higher likelihood of cuts at the ends of groups; it would probably be better to generate a new random location until it doesn't intersect a group.)

But it's also valid (as Pete notes) to have genes which aren't meaningful (ignored) based on other genes; if the combination is anti-survival it will be selected out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but it doesn't answer all aspects of my questions - as even if I group them to not be separated, inside the group the respective values can still bee meaningless.
I'm thinking about implementing a logic inside the Mapper which reads the chromosome, so that some genes are decoded depending on previous ones. Would this make sense for you?